# How to keep radio button selected after refresh the jsp page click in radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring

I have two radio button, i want to refresh a page after click in the radio button how could i do this, i thought too much but not able to do it, i need your help.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click', 'input[type=radio][name=test1]', function() 
            { 
            var clicked = localStorage['clicked'];
           $('.' + related_class).prop('disabled', false); 
          $('input[type=radio][name=test1]').not(':checked').each(function()
             { var other_class = $(this).val(); 
          $('.' + other_class).prop('disabled', true); 
        }); 
      });
   });    
 </script>
```

Here is the first radio button for employee

```
<td>
    <label for="radio1">
        <input type="radio" name="test1" value="radio1" /><b>Employee</b>
    </label>    
    Select Employee 
        <input type="image" img  src="resources/image/search.png"name="for_radio1[]" class="radio1"  disabled="true" onclick="openWindow()"/> 
</td>
```

And here is the another radio button for role.

```
<td>
    <form action="/Submitrole" method="post" model="command">
        <label for="radio2"><input type="radio" name="test1" value="radio2"/>Role </label><br>
                        Select Role :<select  name="roleName"  class="radio2" disabled="true" style="width: 80px;">
                                        <c:forEach items="${listRole}" var="role">
                                            <option value="${role.roleName}">
                                                    <c:out value="${role.roleName}" />
                                            </option>
                                        </c:forEach>
                                    </select>
        <input type="submit" value ="Check">
    </form>
</td>
```

Controller.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/compplan", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView listRules(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request,HttpSession session, SessionStatus status) {

    roleApi.listOfRoles();
    ruleApi.listOfRules();

    model.addAttribute("listRole", roleApi.listOfRoles());
    model.addAttribute("listRules", ruleApi.listOfRules());
    RoleUI object = (RoleUI) request.getSession().getAttribute("roleName");
    if (object != null ) {
        RuleAssignment rAssdtail = ruleAssApi.searchAssignedRule(object.getRoleName());
        List<RuleAssignmentDetails> ptr1 = rAssdtail.getRuleAssignmentDetails();
        ArrayList<Rule> rl1 = new ArrayList<Rule>();
        List<RuleParameter> parameterList = new ArrayList<RuleParameter>();
        Iterator<RuleAssignmentDetails> it1 = ptr1.iterator();
        while (it1.hasNext()) {
            RuleAssignmentDetails rp = (RuleAssignmentDetails) it1.next();
            Rule r1 = rp.getRule();
            List<RuleParameter> ptr2 = r1.getRuleParameter();
            Iterator it = ptr2.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                RuleParameter r2 = (RuleParameter) it.next();
                parameterList.add(r2);
            }
            rl1.add(r1);
        }       
        model.addAttribute("List2", rl1);
        status.setComplete();
        session.removeAttribute("roleName");
       return new ModelAndView("CompPlan"); 
    }

    EmployeeUI object1 = (EmployeeUI) request.getSession().getAttribute("EmployeeName");
    if(object1 != null) {

        RuleAssignment rAssdtail = ruleAssApi.searchAssignedRule(object1.getEmployeeName());
        List<RuleAssignmentDetails> ptr1 = rAssdtail.getRuleAssignmentDetails();
        ArrayList<RuleAssignmentDetails> ruleList1 = new ArrayList<RuleAssignmentDetails>();
        ArrayList<Rule> rl1 = new ArrayList<Rule>();
        List<RuleParameter> parameterList = new ArrayList<RuleParameter>();
        Iterator<RuleAssignmentDetails> it1 = ptr1.iterator();
        while (it1.hasNext()) {

            RuleAssignmentDetails rp = (RuleAssignmentDetails) it1.next();
            Rule r1 = rp.getRule();
            List<RuleParameter> ptr2 = r1.getRuleParameter();

            Iterator it = ptr2.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                RuleParameter r = (RuleParameter) it.next();        
                parameterList.add(r);
            }
            rl1.add(r1);
        }
        model.addAttribute("List2", rl1);
        status.setComplete();
        session.removeAttribute("EmployeeName");
        request.getParameter("test1");
        return new ModelAndView("CompPlan");    
    }   
return new ModelAndView("CompPlan");

}
```

How could i do this, Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  to invoke a function like this when the event on click occurs for that button

```
<script> 
    function refreshPage {  
        window.location.reload();
    }
</script>
```

Edit:
After selecting the radio, get that value in your server code and send it to the jsp as a request Parameter or Attribute. So, when the jsp is reloaded, you have the already selected two value. At any point of your jsp you can tracker that value as

```
request.getParameter("name")
```

And you can just select it for your radio.

EDIT:

Well, I understand you're using any kind of MVC pattern. Supposing you have a servlet (or any controller redirected to after JSP reloads) you can get the radio button value and store in a variable. Something like:

```
String rValue = request.getParameter("radioButtonName");
```

After that, you just send a response from your servlet to the same JSP but, including the value of your radio button. You have 2 options

Send the value as a resquest parameter:

```
String yourJsp = "/theJsp.jsp?radioValue=" + rValue;
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(yourJsp)dispatcher.forward(request,response);
```

Get the value in your JSP as:

```
<%=request.getParameter("radioValue")>
```

Or send the value as a resquest attribute in your servlet (controller) (I prefer this one):

```
...
request.setAttribute("radioValue", rValue);
...
```

Get the value in your JSP as:

```
<%= request.getAttribute("radioValue")>
```

Finally, how to set the value of your radio button selected? Try something like

```
<input type="radio" name="test1" value="radio1" <%= request.getAttribute("radioValue").equals("radio1")?"checked":""/><b>Employee</b>
```

The key is that you can get the idea of all of this (take into account it's a brief descritpion). I can't test it right now but I hope it work.

Comment: this function is working but after selecting the radio button the selected radio button is also refreshed, i want to keep that selected after refreshed the page.

Comment: Sir please could you tell me in little bit details, Actuly i am new in javascript, i dont understand where i write that request.getParameter("name"), in my controller or in jsp;

Comment: Let me get to the office and I'll try to explain in more details

Comment: @ Jorge, ok Thank you sir, I am waiting for your kind help

Comment: Add the radio button value to your model as an attribute and so you will receive it in your jsp. Don't forget to compare with null...

Comment: Sorry sir, i don't understand, how do i add radio button value to model as an attribute,

Comment: In your controller "String rSelectedValue = request.getAttribute("radioName");model.addAttribute("radioName", rSelectedValue)" ...

Comment: @ Jorge,Sir i did the same what ever you suggest me, but still i am not able to fix this problem,actually problem is here, i think i am not placing the code in proper place,You help me a lot i am highly appreciate your help sir.

Comment: @ Jorge,Sir , when i am put <input type="radio" name="test1" value="radio1" <%= request.getAttribute("radioValue").equals("radio1")?"checked":""/><b>Employee</b> its gives an error,

Comment: For each radio option, before printing it, check if it has been selected: <% String checked = request.getAttribute("radioValue").equals("radioNameXxxx")?"checked":"" %> Then in your 'input' tag for that radio <input type="radio" name="test1" value="radio1" <%= checked  %>/><b>Employee</b‌​>. That will include the word "checked" in the radio button which has been previously selected, and so, you will see it as selected

Comment: @ Jorge,Sir  its just radio button its not contain any value, its just contain with some field, which are enable when i select the radio button.

Answer (score 1):

You can use location.reload();
More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp)

Comment: but in my case how could i replicate it..??

Comment: Add it to your click handler of the radio button which you want to refresh the page

Comment: @ Areca this is working, but that radio button is also refreshed which i select, i want to keep that button selected. after refreshing the page